# can you give me an example of cross domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

For example i have a 2 domain "http://domain1.com/info.php" and the other one is "http://domain2.com/script.html"

now the first domain "http://domain1.com/info.php" is releasing json encoded data like this

```
{
    "str_info": [
        {
            "str_name": "Mark",
            "str_age": "22"
        },
        {
            "str_name": "Aliza",
            "str_age": "52"
        }
    ]
}
```

what the second domain "http://domain2.com/script.html" does is to retrieve and manipulate the data given by the first domain.

i don't know how to connect and retrieve the data came from the first domain which is "http://domain1.com/info.php" to the second domain which is the script.
so can you please show me how using jsonp, jquery, ajax if possible

Comment: JSON-P is what you're looking for, see http://json-p.org/

Comment: can you show me how to use ajax with jsonp i don't know how do i start with this.. tnx for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery.org

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
>
> Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

If working crossdomain you can use a method called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
The ajax request adds a parameter `?callback=callbackname` and your server answers with

```
callbackname
(
    {
        "str_info": [
            {
                "str_name": "Mark",
                "str_age": "22"
            },
            {
                "str_name": "Aliza",
                "str_age": "52"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

The function then is executed on your client.
You can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get this done very simple

```
$.getJSON("http://domain1.com/info.php?callback=?", function(data) {
  alert("success");
});
```

in PHP you would wrap your result like this (simple example)

```
echo $_GET['callback'], '(' , json_encode( $data ), ')';
```

Comment: , function(data) { alert(data); })

Comment: Yeah, you're right - better example

Answer (score 0):

send the data with a callback function such as

```
callback({
  "str_info":[{"str_name":"Mark","str_age":"22"},{"str_name":"Aliza","str_age":"52"}]
});
```

and then on the domain receiving data use the function

```
<script>
    function callback(i){
    //maniputlate i (json data) here
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain1.com/info.php"/>
```

Comment: and load in a script tag - as JSONP

Comment: sorry should have mentioned, but kind of thought using a callback and function means load in a script tag was self explanatory :P